# create Tookens problem

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

For some time I have been writing my own tooken. I call it COIN
I come across the last three problems:
my fallback function does not work
code:
function () payable {
        createTookens ();

he gives an error message to the createTookens

then I want my initial supply to be different than my total supply.
For example, I want total supply 100 and the initial supply at the crowdsale 75. which still leaves 25 COINS.
Is it true that the 3 now stand for 1000 COINS for 1 ETH?
code:
totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** 3 uint256 (decimals);
er is a error with the uint256 and the initialSupply

and my last question
can I also accept 0.1 eth with a crowdsale for payment?
I know that solidity does not work with decimals. So how can I put that in a code ?

Comment: This would be great if you can put code blocks along with the questions. For your last question, check : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/how-can-i-perform-float-type-division-in-solidity/8686#8686

Answer (score -1):

problem 2

> totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 **3 uint256(decimals);

problem 1

> function () payable {
>           createTookens();

```
}
```

thank you for the answer of my third question. I need to do it in Finney. but how to put in a code like this ?

> uint256 public constant RATE = 3000;
>
> RATE = 1000 Finney
>
> uint256 public constant RATE = 300 == 100 Finney;