# Uint256 division in vyper (and solidity)

Tags: vyper

Floating point division is not supported in solidity as mentioned here: [How can I perform float type division in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/how-can-i-perform-float-type-division-in-solidity)

I want to divide two uint256 numbers and save them as a decimal, retaining 10 decimal places of accuracy. Would I need to multiply these numbers by 10000000000 first and then divide them by each other, then save the decimal and then divide the decimal by 10000000000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two uint a and b, and you wish, to divide a by b -> `a/b` with 10 decimals, then you can do the following

```
uint aScaled = a * 10**10;
uint divScaled = a / b;            // b is not scaled!

uint decN    = divScaled / 10**10;
uint decFrac = divScaled % 10**10
```

Example

```
a = 3; b = 2;
aScaled   = 3 * 10000000000;           // = 30000000000
divScaled = 30000000000 / 2;           // = 15000000000
decN      = 15000000000 / 10000000000; // = 1
decFrac   = 15000000000 mod 1000000000;// = 5000000000
```

I would keep the number scaled by 10**10 and present it only as a decimal in the UI.