# Is there a good way to calculate a ratio in Solidity (since there is no float/double)?

Tags: solidity

I've looked into the following answers, but have not found what I am looking for.

- [How can I perform float type division in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/how-can-i-perform-float-type-division-in-solidity)
- [How can I represent decimal values in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-can-i-represent-decimal-values-in-solidity)
- [How does Ethereum cope with division of prime numbers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/how-does-ethereum-cope-with-division-of-prime-numbers)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use fixed-point arithmetic. Have you seen [this example of solidity code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738640/division-in-ethereum-solidity) that calculate percentage with given precision?

Comment: @blockchaindotsol What are you looking for that is not solved in the links you have pointed to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As seen in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739843) *copying and pasting shamelessly to keep the users here.*

It's probably best (lowest gas cost and trivial to implement) to perform that calculation on the client rather than in Solidity.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Divide {

  function percent(uint numerator, uint denominator, uint precision) public 

  constant returns(uint quotient) {

         // caution, check safe-to-multiply here
        uint _numerator  = numerator * 10 ** (precision+1);
        // with rounding of last digit
        uint _quotient =  ((_numerator / denominator) + 5) / 10;
        return ( _quotient);
  }

}
```

If you feed it 101,450, 3 you get 224, i.e. 22.4%.